Set layouts order in react-map-gl
I'm using from react-map-gl and maplibre-gl in a react project, I created Source and Layer like this:
import Map from "react-map-gl/maplibre";

return (
    <Map>   
        <LineComponent/>
        <MarkerCompnent/>
    </Map>
)

LineComponent:
import Layer from "react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/layer";
import Source from "react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/source";

const lineLayer = {
    id: "lines",
    type: "line",
};

const sourceData = {
    return {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: arr.map((item) => ({
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: item.geom,
      })),
    }
}

return (
    <Source data={sourceData}>
        <Layer {...lineLayer}/>
    </Source>
)

MarkerCompnent:
import Layer from "react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/layer";
import Source from "react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/source";

const markerLayer = {
    id: "markers",
    type: "symbol"
}

const sourceData = {
    return {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: arr.map((item) => ({
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: item.geom,
      })),
    }
}

return (
    <Source data={sourceData}>
        <Layer {...markerLayer}/>
    </Source>
)

I want to set the order of these layers, i.e. the lines are shown first and then the markers (markers on the lines),
But sometimes the markers are shown below the lines, what is your suggestion to solve this problem?
